# Application unable to work due to rate limiter

Tags: html, node.js, express

I have tried to implement rate limiter on server.js but it gives this error below making the website crash. Did I implement the rate limiter wrongly? I have tried changing the rate and apiLimiter line position but it didnt work. Below server.js is the error log. As this is the first time I encounter this error log issue, I am not sure where to look for the issue. This is my first time implementing rate limiter in server.js so please advice.

```
Application error
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served
```

server.js

```
import express from 'express'
import path from 'path'
import mongoose from 'mongoose'
import cors from 'cors'
import rateLimit from 'express-rate-limiter'
import config from './config'
import userRoute from './routes/userRoute'
import uploadRoute from './routes/uploadRoute'
import productRoute from './routes/productRoute'
import orderRoute from './routes/orderRoute'

const mongodbUrl = config.MONGODB_URL;
mongoose.connect(mongodbUrl, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
  }).catch((error) => console.log(error.reason))

const app = express()

const apiLimiter = rateLimit({
  windowMs: 15 * 60 * 1000, // 15 minutes
  max: 100
})

app.use(cors())
app.use(express.json())
app.use('/api/', apiLimiter)
app.use('/api/users', userRoute)
app.use('/api/uploads', uploadRoute)
app.use('/api/products', productRoute)
app.use('/api/orders', orderRoute)
app.get('/api/paypal/clientId', (req, res) => {
  res.send({ clientId: config.PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID })
})

app.use('/uploads', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/../uploads')))
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/../frontend')))
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(`${__dirname}/../frontend/index.html`)) 
})

// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  const status = err.name && err.name === 'ValidationError' ? 400 : 500
  res.status(status)
  res.send({ message: err.message })
})
```

```
2021-05-29T05:11:02.707267+00:00 app[web.1]: this.__configuration = this.__buildConfiguration(options);
2021-05-29T05:11:02.707268+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2021-05-29T05:11:02.707268+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-05-29T05:11:02.707269+00:00 app[web.1]: TypeError: this.__buildConfiguration is not a function
2021-05-29T05:11:02.707269+00:00 app[web.1]: at module.exports (/app/node_modules/express-rate-limiter/index.js:13:33)
2021-05-29T05:11:02.707270+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/dist/server.js:34:49)
2021-05-29T05:11:02.707270+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:774:30)
2021-05-29T05:11:02.707270+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:785:10)
2021-05-29T05:11:02.707271+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:641:32)
2021-05-29T05:11:02.707271+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:556:12)   
2021-05-29T05:11:02.707272+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:837:10) 
2021-05-29T05:11:02.707272+00:00 app[web.1]: at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11
2021-05-29T05:11:02.778624+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-05-29T05:11:02.853093+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-05-29T05:11:59.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user hillery262627@gmail.com
2021-05-29T05:13:01.344269+00:00 app[api]: Deploy c8670dff by user hillery262627@gmail.com
2021-05-29T05:13:01.344269+00:00 app[api]: Release v88 created by user hillery262627@gmail.com
2021-05-29T05:13:02.041520+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-05-29T05:13:03.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2021-05-29T05:13:06.356963+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node dist/server.js`
2021-05-29T05:13:10.148201+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/node_modules/express-rate-limiter/index.js:13
2021-05-29T05:13:10.148263+00:00 app[web.1]: this.__configuration = this.__buildConfiguration(options);
2021-05-29T05:13:10.148272+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2021-05-29T05:13:10.148276+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-05-29T05:13:10.148276+00:00 app[web.1]: TypeError: this.__buildConfiguration is not a function
2021-05-29T05:13:10.148279+00:00 app[web.1]: at module.exports (/app/node_modules/express-rate-limiter/index.js:13:33)
2021-05-29T05:13:10.148279+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/dist/server.js:34:49)
2021-05-29T05:13:10.148280+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:774:30)
2021-05-29T05:13:10.148280+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:785:10)
2021-05-29T05:13:10.148280+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:641:32)
2021-05-29T05:13:10.148280+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:556:12)   
2021-05-29T05:13:10.148280+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:837:10) 
2021-05-29T05:13:10.148281+00:00 app[web.1]: at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11
2021-05-29T05:13:10.200115+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-05-29T05:13:10.283484+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-05-29T05:17:48.336323+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=revivaproject.herokuapp.com request_id=3f033042-c6d3-4c4b-bdbe-d0badd2d3d34 fwd="49.245.39.161" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-05-29T05:23:09.940782+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-05-29T05:23:13.553102+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node dist/server.js`
2021-05-29T05:23:16.251662+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/node_modules/express-rate-limiter/index.js:13
2021-05-29T05:23:16.251678+00:00 app[web.1]: this.__configuration = this.__buildConfiguration(options);
2021-05-29T05:23:16.251678+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2021-05-29T05:23:16.251679+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-05-29T05:23:16.251679+00:00 app[web.1]: TypeError: this.__buildConfiguration is not a function
2021-05-29T05:23:16.251680+00:00 app[web.1]: at module.exports (/app/node_modules/express-rate-limiter/index.js:13:33)
2021-05-29T05:23:16.251680+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/dist/server.js:34:49)
2021-05-29T05:23:16.251681+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:774:30)
2021-05-29T05:23:16.251681+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:785:10)
2021-05-29T05:23:16.251682+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:641:32)
2021-05-29T05:23:16.251682+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:556:12)   
2021-05-29T05:23:16.251683+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:837:10) 
2021-05-29T05:23:16.251683+00:00 app[web.1]: at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11
2021-05-29T05:23:16.318206+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-05-29T05:23:16.378564+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-05-29T05:24:33.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user hillery262627@gmail.com
2021-05-29T05:25:34.946347+00:00 app[api]: Release v89 created by user hillery262627@gmail.com
2021-05-29T05:25:34.946347+00:00 app[api]: Deploy c8670dff by user hillery262627@gmail.com
2021-05-29T05:25:35.219700+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-05-29T05:25:37.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2021-05-29T05:25:38.314459+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node dist/server.js`
2021-05-29T05:25:40.788755+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/node_modules/express-rate-limiter/index.js:13
2021-05-29T05:25:40.788776+00:00 app[web.1]: this.__configuration = this.__buildConfiguration(options);
2021-05-29T05:25:40.788777+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2021-05-29T05:25:40.788778+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-05-29T05:25:40.788778+00:00 app[web.1]: TypeError: this.__buildConfiguration is not a function
2021-05-29T05:25:40.788779+00:00 app[web.1]: at module.exports (/app/node_modules/express-rate-limiter/index.js:13:33)
2021-05-29T05:25:40.788779+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/dist/server.js:34:49)
2021-05-29T05:25:40.788779+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:774:30)
2021-05-29T05:25:40.788780+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:785:10)
2021-05-29T05:25:40.788780+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:641:32)
2021-05-29T05:25:40.788780+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:556:12)   
2021-05-29T05:25:40.788781+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:837:10) 
2021-05-29T05:25:40.788781+00:00 app[web.1]: at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11
2021-05-29T05:25:40.864253+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-05-29T05:25:40.952164+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-05-29T05:34:33.335208+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=revivaproject.herokuapp.com request_id=3a904ea7-930c-42e6-a9af-16e333a4064a fwd="49.245.39.161" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-05-29T05:37:25.482013+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=revivaproject.herokuapp.com request_id=ebd52cb6-bb09-481b-bdb7-91d8c8993766 fwd="49.245.39.161" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-05-29T05:37:26.504268+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=revivaproject.herokuapp.com request_id=f7f3e1ec-ea62-4ea9-8712-b1178c56abca fwd="49.245.39.161" dyno= 
connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-05-29T05:38:36.526750+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=revivaproject.herokuapp.com request_id=0402ac65-49cb-4b09-a44e-6aaf428c23dd fwd="49.245.39.161" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-05-29T05:38:37.438382+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=revivaproject.herokuapp.com request_id=4389454b-a233-45d8-bf60-a3f0e7349504 fwd="49.245.39.161" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-05-29T06:09:11.655622+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-05-29T06:09:15.444774+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node dist/server.js`
2021-05-29T06:09:17.936977+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/node_modules/express-rate-limiter/index.js:13
2021-05-29T06:09:17.937002+00:00 app[web.1]: this.__configuration = this.__buildConfiguration(options);
2021-05-29T06:09:17.937003+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2021-05-29T06:09:17.937003+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-05-29T06:09:17.937003+00:00 app[web.1]: TypeError: this.__buildConfiguration is not a function
2021-05-29T06:09:17.937004+00:00 app[web.1]: at module.exports (/app/node_modules/express-rate-limiter/index.js:13:33)
2021-05-29T06:09:17.937004+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/dist/server.js:34:49)
2021-05-29T06:09:17.937005+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:774:30)
2021-05-29T06:09:17.937005+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:785:10)
2021-05-29T06:09:17.937005+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:641:32)
2021-05-29T06:09:17.937006+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:556:12)
2021-05-29T06:09:17.937006+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:837:10)
2021-05-29T06:09:17.937007+00:00 app[web.1]: at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11
2021-05-29T06:09:17.980716+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-05-29T06:09:18.047009+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-05-29T06:48:19.910733+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=revivaproject.herokuapp.com request_id=b65d1d7c-50b2-4b63-b305-400459ed69ba fwd="49.245.39.161" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-05-29T06:48:21.301919+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=revivaproject.herokuapp.com request_id=61fe1968-f463-4c52-b3a8-8d517d0a157d fwd="49.245.39.161" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-05-29T06:48:33.577825+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=revivaproject.herokuapp.com request_id=9831ac5d-869a-4f05-a2f3-6a0422efba77 fwd="49.245.39.161" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-05-29T06:48:34.410206+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=revivaproject.herokuapp.com request_id=cd55e067-ced5-4689-a815-5725e7daa151 fwd="49.245.39.161" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-05-29T06:55:56.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user hillery262627@gmail.com
2021-05-29T06:56:52.630557+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-05-29T06:56:52.473357+00:00 app[api]: Deploy e28a52be by user hillery262627@gmail.com
2021-05-29T06:56:52.473357+00:00 app[api]: Release v90 created by user hillery262627@gmail.com
2021-05-29T06:56:54.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2021-05-29T06:56:55.920729+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node dist/server.js`
2021-05-29T06:56:58.334876+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-05-29T06:56:58.401966+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-05-29T06:56:58.405968+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-05-29T06:56:58.278359+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/node_modules/express-rate-limiter/index.js:13
2021-05-29T06:56:58.278373+00:00 app[web.1]: this.__configuration = this.__buildConfiguration(options);
2021-05-29T06:56:58.278374+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2021-05-29T06:56:58.278374+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-05-29T06:56:58.278374+00:00 app[web.1]: TypeError: this.__buildConfiguration is not a function    
2021-05-29T06:56:58.278375+00:00 app[web.1]: at module.exports (/app/node_modules/express-rate-limiter/index.js:13:33)
2021-05-29T06:56:58.278375+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/dist/server.js:34:52)
2021-05-29T06:56:58.278375+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:774:30)
2021-05-29T06:56:58.278376+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:785:10)
2021-05-29T06:56:58.278376+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:641:32)
2021-05-29T06:56:58.278376+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:556:12)
2021-05-29T06:56:58.278377+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:837:10)
2021-05-29T06:56:58.278377+00:00 app[web.1]: at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11
2021-05-29T06:57:01.716901+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node dist/server.js`
2021-05-29T06:57:04.120156+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-05-29T06:57:04.188477+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-05-29T06:57:04.078916+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/node_modules/express-rate-limiter/index.js:13
2021-05-29T06:57:04.078967+00:00 app[web.1]: this.__configuration = this.__buildConfiguration(options);
2021-05-29T06:57:04.078967+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2021-05-29T06:57:04.078968+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-05-29T06:57:04.078968+00:00 app[web.1]: TypeError: this.__buildConfiguration is not a function
2021-05-29T06:57:04.078982+00:00 app[web.1]: at module.exports (/app/node_modules/express-rate-limiter/index.js:13:33)
2021-05-29T06:57:04.078983+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/dist/server.js:34:52)
2021-05-29T06:57:04.078983+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:774:30)
2021-05-29T06:57:04.078983+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:785:10)
2021-05-29T06:57:04.078983+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:641:32)
2021-05-29T06:57:04.078984+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:556:12)
2021-05-29T06:57:04.078984+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:837:10)
2021-05-29T06:57:04.078984+00:00 app[web.1]: at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11
2021-05-29T06:57:05.387430+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=revivaproject.herokuapp.com request_id=54289191-9ec6-4ca9-ad4c-49395f5b3bf4 fwd="49.245.39.161" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Comment: Are you using https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-rate-limit? If so, you should use: `import rateLimit from 'express-rate-limit'`. The other library is https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-rate-limiter, but it uses other configuration methods.

Comment: ohh thank you so much!!! i didnt realise there was two different type of rate limit npm library

Answer (score 0):

At line 5, you need to import 'express-rate-limit' not 'express-rate-limiter'